# Pods/Farbric/upload-symbols does not upload my dSYM-file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I'am using a script in my build-phases where I entered following:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"

find "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}" -name "${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}" | xargs -I \{\} $PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp $SRCROOT/$GOOGLE_SERVICE_PLIST_FILE -p ios \{\}
```

and my build-monitoring is showing me the following:

```
2017-12-11 09:51:03.692 upload-symbols[28339:5705695] Successfully 
submitted symbols for architecture x86_64 with UUID 07cd69b..... 
in dSYM: /Users/thisuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-
anyuuq......./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app.dSYM
```

but my firebase-console (crashlytics) is still showing me the "missing dsyms-popup"

any ideas?

Comment: Does the UUID of the dSYM that's being uploaded match the UUID that's missing in the dashboard?

Comment: Same issue here, and no..the UUIDs do not match...have no clue why though.. @Sandu where you able to resolve this?

Comment: @EugeneGordin since I updated my Pods, it worked for me. Actually I'm using `Firebase 4.8.2`, `Fabric 1.7.3` & `Crashlytics 3.10.0`. It is now also possible to upload the missing dsyms afterwards at the firebase-crashlytics-web-dashboard

Comment: @EugeneGordin my problem was that the lib was uploading the wrong dsym